# How can I build the Android kernel for pixel 4

Tags: android-source, android-kernel

I try to build the Android kernel for pixel 4 .

```
export ARCH=arm64

export CROSS_COMPILE=/home/xxx/AOSP/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-

make floral_defconfig (not sure)

make
```

I failed with an error:

```
arch/arm64/Makefile:49: LSE atomics not supported by binutils
arch/arm64/Makefile:57: Detected assembler with broken .inst; disassembly will be unreliable
arch/arm64/Makefile:83: *** CROSS_COMPILE_ARM32 not defined or empty, the compat vDSO will not be built.  Stop.
```

I had try `export CC_FOR_BUILD=clang` ,it didn't work.

How Should I solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite self explanatory above, you haven't defined certain variables.
Try to follow these guides, very helpful:

https://github.com/nathanchance/android-kernel-clang

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/reference-how-to-compile-an-android-kernel.3627297/